# Showing Store fields in Zenbu

Tags: expresso-store, zenbu

Does any one know if there is a way to display Exp-resso Store fields like Price in the Zenbu entries display? It'd be super-cooper nice for users.

Comment: Not that I'm aware of, I haven't heard any reports of this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Zenbu on its own will show what is stored in `exp_channel_data`. Store isn't supported per-se, but can be made more compatible by adding Zenbu support by the third-party add-on developer.

According to [Store's release notes](https://exp-resso.com/docs/release_notes.html), it doesn’t look like full Zenbu support has been added (as of this writing).
I recommend contacting the developers of Store and ask for Zenbu support.
[Developer documentation for Zenbu has been available for a while](http://zenbustudio.com/software/dev/zenbu).

For completeness, here are some [answers from the FAQ section on zenbustudio.com](http://zenbustudio.com/software/faq/zenbu) on the subject:

> **My custom field does not display as expected, why is that?**
>
> By default, Zenbu displays data as it is found in the exp_channel_data database table. A few common custom fields have extended support which shows an enhanced display based off the exp_channel_data data. Customized Zenbu display support for third-party fieldtypes can be easily added by third-party developers by adding Zenbu functions in the third-party add-on’s code. Documentation for adding third-party field support for Zenbu can be found [here](http://zenbustudio.com/software/dev/zenbu).
>
> **Does Zenbu support (insert third-party add-on here)?**
>
> Natively within Zenbu, likely no. Only a few custom fields have support within Zenbu (including native EE custom fields). Other custom fields will at least display the contents of exp_channel_data by default. Customized Zenbu display support for third-party fieldtypes can be easily added by third-party developers by adding Zenbu functions in the third-party add-on’s code. Documentation for adding third-party field support for Zenbu can be found [here](http://zenbustudio.com/software/dev/zenbu).